# How to upgrade to Opengl 2.0 on linux (nouveau)?

Tags: python, linux, opengl

I ran the python-kivy hello world test program, but got a blank screen.  An error message warned:

```
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <1.5 Mesa 9.2.2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <nouveau>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Gallium 0.4 on NV31>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 1, 5
[CRITICAL] [GL          ] Minimum required OpenGL version (2.0) NOT found!
```

It seems I need to upgrade opengl.

Mesa 9.2.2 supports opengl 3.1 (http://www.mesa3d.org/relnotes/9.2.2.html). All the other opengl related packages are up to date, including freeglut3 (2.8.1-1).  I think the issue might lie with my nouveau version.  I have the 2.4.51-1 libdrm-nouveau2 and 1:1.0.10-1 xserver-xorg-video-nouveau packages installed, which are very recent versions.  There doesn't look to be enough info on the nouveau homepage to work out which opengl version they support/implement.

I'm not really sure how to get opengl 2.0 running.  Other answers on google elude to graphics driver implementations (?) of opengl, but are quite vague and cryptic about the details.

Answer (score 0):

Nouveau is still in a very experimental stage. So far people usually go with the NVidia proprietary binary drivers, which you can download from NVidia's website; also there are packages for most distributions as well.

In case of a NV31 it's the only driver with OpenGL-2.0 support.

Comment: Unfortunately, nvidia stopped supporting the driver that worked with my monitor (version 96).  Support for the nvidia driver version 173 is set to end soon enough.

Comment: @shafty: Just out of interest: Are you stuck with that old GeForceFX? I mean, you can get OpenGL-4.2 capable "low end" NVidia GPUs for 40$ which will easily outperform that NV31.

Comment: datenwolf: I'm using a laptop, so unfortunately I can't upgrade the GPU.

Comment: @shafty: Well, then, until Mesa gains NV31 feature parity you're SOL.